# Passing value from one html to another using cookie is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I want to obtain the user input in a search field in one html and display the input in another html file. So I discovered the best method is to save the entered input as a cookie in html file1 and retrieve the cookie in html file2.

So I used these steps

1. created a cookie.js file (added the getcookie and setcookie functions)
2. Set cookie in html1
3. Get cookie in html2

this is my cookie.js file

```
console.log("Cookie file activated");
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
if (x==c_name)
 {
  return unescape(y);
 }
 }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; 
expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;

}
```

in html1 file

```
   <form action='Display.html' method='GET' class="search-container" name="site-search" role="search">
    <input type="text" name="sch" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search Name?">
    <button class="search-icon" id="searchbtn" 
    </button>
</form>

 window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("search-bar").onkeyup = function() {
        setCookie("shared", this.value, 1);
         console.log(this.value)
    };
};
```

in html2 file

```
<h1 id="here">Display cookie value here</h1>


var checkandupdate = function() {
       var shared = getCookie("shared");
       if(shared) {
        console.log(shared);

          document.getElementById("here").value = shared;
       }
};

window.onload = function() {
    int = setInterval(checkandupdate(),1000);
    checkandupdate();
};
```

it shows that the cookie file is activate in both html1 and 2 console log. But I can't get the search value to display in html2. What am I doing wrongly and how can I fix it?

Comment: `int = setInterval(checkandupdate(),1000);` <--- wrong

Comment: For reference: `int = setInterval(checkandupdate,1000);` <--- right

Comment: @epascarello how is it wrong and what is the correct way?

Comment: document.getElementById("here").value  should be document.getElementById("here").textContent

Comment: @MrZach it does not work. I can't even get any value for console.log (shared)

Comment: You should use local or session storage instead of cookies. It has a nice API for usage in JavaScript as well, and is a better and more secure vehicle for application data @learner101

Comment: how can I implement that @bobbyz